# Undefined Index of element input with yii

Tags: php, yii

This has made me confused. I have an input element in form. Then, get the value for adding data into database

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Departemen;
    echo $_POST['nama_departemen'];


        $model->nama_departemen =  $_POST['nama_departemen'];
        $model->keterangan = $_POST['keterangan'];

        if($model->save())
        {
            $this->redirect('departemen/actionIndex');
        }

}
```

But an error occur in the browser

```
Error 500 Undefined index: nama_departemen
```

I am very confused because it is successfully inserted into database. How I fix it?

Comment: Maybe there's no input named "nama_departemen". What does  "echo $_POST['nama_departemen']; "  this prints?

Comment: comment echo $_POST['nama_departemen']; And I suspect your action is index and it should be $this->redirect(array('departemen/index'));

Comment: Actually $_POST['nama_departemen'] already exist. And its value can inserted into database.

Comment: why you are not using model ? `echo $_POST['Departemen']['nama_departemen']`;

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Departemen;

    if(isset($_POST['nama_departemen'])){

        echo $_POST['nama_departemen'];


        $model->nama_departemen =  $_POST['nama_departemen'];
        $model->keterangan = $_POST['keterangan'];

        if($model->save())
        {
            $this->redirect('departemen/actionIndex');
        }
    }

}
```

and to make sure that the index is posted, try to `var_dump($_POST)` and share us the result;

Answer (score 0):

First you should verify the value exists before proceeding to assign it to model value as pointed out by Mohammad. If it saves on the database then your undefined index is on actionIndex where its redirected to after saving.